# Embedding python error Import by filename is not supported

Tags: c++, python

I'm trying to embed python in to my application and have got stuck pretty early on.

I am embedding python into my C++ application and using the code found at this tutorial:
http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding

My application matches entirely and compiles successfully no errors. However on running the application `pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);` line fails returning 0 meaning I get error output from PyErr_Print() of

```
Failed to load "C:\Users\workspace\dpllib\pyscript.py"
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

The application is being called with the commands `C:\Users\workspace\ndnlib\pyscript.py multiply 50 150`

Comment: Did you try double backslash? \\

Comment: Which imports are you using on the python script?

Comment: Actually, non the code in the python file is "def multiply(a,b):..." exactly as given in the tutorial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't be sure, but I'm thinking that since pName is set to argv[1] and you're using the full path to call the script, then argv[1] is the full path. This means the code would try to import "C:\Users\workspace\dpllib\pyscript.py", which python can't (it can only import "pyscript").

Try running the script by just typing "pyscript.py" from within the directory and see if the error changes to 'Failed to load "pyscript.py"'. If it does, then you have to fix it so it doesn't just import argv[1] and modifies the string to get a module name instead of a file name.

Comment: Yes I got this just as you were typing, the file must be local to the exe. Same, directory not even in a sub folder! Must not have the .py extension. Thanks anyway

Comment: Edit sub directories are allowed, but simply load "pyscript" and the search is done for you.

Comment: On ubuntu trying to run it directly led to a permission error, fixed with "chmod +x pyscript.py". However at that point we are stuck with "ImportError: No module named pyscript"

Answer (score 0):

It is simplier if you create your file as a module.

For instance,

create this:

`<project>/MyModule/__init__.py`

Then run your file `<project>/script.py`

```
dyn_module_name = (... get module name 'MyModule' from console arguments ...)
my_dynamic_module = __import__(dyn_module_name)
```

Since it would be a module, it will load while your scripy.py execution