# Debugging Popen subprocesses with PyCharm

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pycharm

I'm trying to debug a Python application that uses psutil.Popen objects. When I start a subprocess, PyCharm replaces my command line with the following:

```
python -m pydevd.py --multiproc --client 127.0.0.1 --port 52581 --file <myapplication>
```

which ends up in an error:

```
python.exe: Import by filename is not supported.
```

When I launch the same command without `-m` option, everything seems to be fine. Is there a way I can change PyCharm's debugger launch command?

I've updated to PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.3 and the new debugger command looks like:

```
python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" 
--multiproc --client 127.0.0.1 --port 62661 
--file __main__.py local -c local.yml -f input/11_12.xls
```

where `-c` and `-f` are my module's command line arguments. The debugger launch command has changed, but it didn't solve the issue; I still get the `Import by filename is not supported` error.

A code example is available [here at Bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/lgyanf/pycharm-multiprocess-debug).
Pycharm's run configuration should look like:

```
Script:            __main__.py
Script parameters: server
Working directory: %path to the repository%
```

Comment: This is a tough one. I gotta look more.

Comment: How does `<myapplication>` look like? Is it only a name or full path? If it's full path then try changing it to name only and make sure the parent folder is in `sys.path`. Compare with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465473/

Comment: Facing the same issue with Community Edition 3.4 (and my 2nd day of python development). Can anyone comment if it worked with previous versions ever?

Comment: I found a workaround for this. First run the script from PyCharm and then attach debugger to the processes (this should show all the subprocesses). Tools --> Attach To Process. Somewhere I read that subprocess debugging is not supported by PyCharm and is planned for V4.

Comment: @Prabhjot From https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/python-debugger.html – *Attach to subprocess automatically while debugging: If this check box is selected, PyCharm will automatically attach all subprocesses of the process being debugged. Thus, if the parent process has subprocesses, their breakpoints will always work.* The feature was already available in PyCharm 2.7 (might be available even before 2.7).

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost `<myapplication>` is a python module `__main__.py` file, not the full path

Comment: Can you provide a code example which can be used to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @yole https://bitbucket.org/lgyanf/pycharm-multiprocess-debug

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost this will work for breakpoints, but not the debug console. See my related posts in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63525050/how-to-debug-code-run-using-popen-in-pycharm and https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009571680-Debugging-code-run-through-subprocess-Popen

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Piotr mentioned, PyCharm 'Attach to subprocess automatically while debugging'. If subprocess is a Python process, PyCharm debugger change the process's startup arguments (see function `patch_args` at [source](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/python/helpers/pydev/pydev_monkey.py)). When you start subprocess in this way:

```
args = ['python',
        '-m', 'pycharm-multiprocess-debug',
        'worker']
worker = subprocess.Popen(args)
```

The actual startup command is like:

```
python.exe -m "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py"
--multiproc --client 127.0.0.1 --port 62661
--file pycharm-multiprocess-debug
```

So it went wrong. There are several workarounds I can find:

1. easiest way, if you don't need to debug subprocess, just turn off "Attach to subprocess automatically while debugging" inside PyCharm settings
2. change your args to:

   ```
   args = ['python', '__main__.py', 'worker']
   ```

   The disadvantage is you can only run a Python file, not a Python module.
3. I recommend the last solution for Python subprocess:

   ```
   from multiprocessing import Process

   def server():
       p = Process(target=worker)
       p.start()
       print 'worker pid: {}'.format(p.pid)
       p.join()
   ```

Comment: where should I write that code?? 
args = ['python', '__main__.py', 'worker']

Comment: @MARCO, the `args` is in Ivan's code sample: https://bitbucket.org/lgyanf/pycharm-multiprocess-debug/src/973bebe2e1c249ff75f5db1e8ddaad0720a0dec5/__main__.py?at=default

Comment: My current command (that doesn't get the Pycharm debugger attached) looks like this: subprocess.Popen("cd /users/lewis/; ENV_VAR=99; python main.py")

Comment: @user3180 you did not mention `shell=True`, but apparently, you have tried to run a shell command sequence. Subprocess debugging will not work with `shell=True`. The program to be run needs to be `'python'` (and I would recommend to use `sys.executable` instead of `'python'` to make sure it is the same Python as the parent). In your case you would also need to pass `cwd` and `env` parameters.