# PyCharm IDE breakpoints don't work in subprocess call

Tags: python, debugging, flask, scrapy, pycharm

I have a **Flask** project running with a subprocess call to a **Scrapy** spider:

```
class Utilities(object):

    @staticmethod
    def scrape(inputs):
        job_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        project_folder = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        subprocess.call(['scrapy', 'crawl', "ExampleCrawler", "-a", "inputs=" + str(inputs), "-s", "JOB_ID=" + job_id],
                            cwd="%s/scraper" % project_folder)
        return job_id
```

Even though **I have 'Attach to subprocess automatically while debugging' enabled** in the projects' Python debugger, the breakpoints inside the spider won't work. The first breakpoint which works again would be one on `return job_id`.

Here is a part of the code from the spider where I expect the breakpoints to work:

```
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from Handelsregister_Scraper.scraper.items import Product
import re


class ExampleCrawler(Spider):
    name = "ExampleCrawler"

    def __init__(self, inputs='', *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleCrawler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_urls = ['https://www.example-link.com']
        self.inputs = inputs

    def parse(self, response):
        yield FormRequest(self.start_urls[0], callback=self.parse_list_elements, formdata=self.inputs)
```

I can't find any solution to this other than enabling said option which i did.

Any suggestions how to get breakpoints inside the spider work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debugger doesn't work because is not a subprocess, but an external call. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27618724/4353946) for possible workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring this python running configuration in "Edit Configurations". After that, run in debug mode.

[image: Example]