cant't debug python in subproces?
I am a Python beginner. I downloaded a poetry management framework from GitHub. In this framework, the external file is a main.py file. Use main.py to call the encapsulated management command to initiate the call. Like this
    try:
        management.call_command(action, *services, *start_args)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        logging.info('Cancel ...')
        time.sleep(2)

I found the encapsulated command logic, below is
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        service = options.get('service')
        os.environ.setdefault('CELERY_NAME', ','.join(service))
        server_hostname = os.environ.get("SERVER_HOSTNAME")
        if hasattr(os, 'getuid') and os.getuid() == 0:
            os.environ.setdefault('C_FORCE_ROOT', '1')
        if not server_hostname:
            server_hostname = '%h'
        cmd = [
            'celery',
            '-A', 'ops',
            'worker',
            '-P', 'threads',
            '-l', 'info',
            '-c', '10',
            '-Q', ','.join(service),
            '--heartbeat-interval', '10',
            '-n', f'{",".join(service)}@{server_hostname}',
            '--without-mingle',
        ]
        kwargs = {'cwd': BASE_DIR}

        print("===== args ======∂")
        print(cmd)
        print("===== args ======∂")
        print(kwargs)
        subprocess.run(cmd, **kwargs)

The current situation is that if I set a breakpoint in main.py, I can debug the contents of main.py. However, I cannot debug the breakpoint in the business class started by the command. However, I can debug directly using manage.py. But this is meaningless.
I have tried to google it many times but failed. Can anyone help me?

Could you give more details please about the way you setting a breakpoint? Is it just breakpoint of Pycharm?

This framework provides a web validation interface. I set breakpoints in it and manually added some print statements. When I start to use the web interface to access it, it will pass through this method. However, the breakpoint did not stop, and my print statements were printed in my log. It was executed.
The code is as follows . the breakpoint in first line
    def valid(self, is_valid=True):
        if is_valid:
                print(' ===========================')
                print('sjdfoe%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%')
               


PyCharm will only debug the subprocess if it's a python subprocess check out this answer for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465221/debugging-popen-subprocesses-with-pycharm/27618724#27618724
